# Perform a function if a variable changes

Tags: ios, swift

I want to perform

```
func performSegue() {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toTabSegue", sender: self)
}
```

immediately when

```
var isUpdated:Bool = false
```

is true.

How do I set something in viewdidload so when isUpdated changes to true it performs a segue?

Comment: What class contains `isUpdated`? The same class that contains `performSegue`?

Comment: This [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) can be useful to you.

Comment: it is in the same view controller as where I want to perform segue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `didSet` observer:

```
var isUpdated = false {
    didSet {
        if isUpdated && !oldValue {
            performSegue()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that Swift provides `oldValue` in `didSet` automatically.